# How do I check for non-word characters within a single word in Java?

Tags: java, string

I want to know if a String such as "equi-distant" or "they're" contains a non-word character. Is there a simple way to check for it?

Comment: What do you mean by "word character"? Can you be specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on what you mean by "word character".

If by "word character" you mean A-Z or a-z then you can use this:

```
bool containsNonWordCharacter = s.matches(".*[^A-Za-z].*");
```

If you mean "any character that is considered to be a letter in Unicode", then look at [`Character.isLetter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) instead.

This is code provided by [bobbymcr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115446/how-do-i-check-for-non-word-characters-within-a-single-word-in-java/8115483#8115483) *nearly* works:

```
public static boolean hasNonWordCharacter(String s) {
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    for (char c : a) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

However see the documentation:

> Note: This method cannot handle supplementary characters. To support all Unicode characters, including supplementary characters, use the isLetter(int) method.

This should work for all Unicode characters:

```
public static boolean hasNonWordCharacter(String s) {

    int offset = 0, strLen = str.length();
    while (offset < strLen) {
        int curChar = str.codePointAt(offset);
        offset += Character.charCount(curChar);
        if (!Character.isLetter(curChar)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Could you explain to me the meaning of that expression?

Comment: I would prefer to use the second definition, you're right. But what is the purpose of the period and the asterisk?

Comment: @user104460: `.*` = match anything.

Comment: @Jeffrey: That's because ó isn't in A-Z or a-z. See my update.

Comment: @bobbymcr: Cool, finally got a vote! Very tough crowd tonight... I'll +1 yours too as thank-you.

Answer (score 6):

Solution without regex (generally faster for a very simple check like this):

```
public static boolean hasNonWordCharacter(String s) {
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    for (char c : a) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: for-each loop cannot be used this way. String is not made up of chars.

Comment: @stratwine: you're right, I fixed the code to get the char array first.

Comment: This only works in basic multilingual plane. See my answer to see why.

Answer (score 2):

I like the non-regex way. But with regex it could be written like this-

```
private static boolean containsNonWord(String toCheck) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*");
        return !p.matcher(toCheck).matches();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java regular expression \w does not support unicode. \b does support unicode under java. I think that most flavours of regex support the standard \w notation [A-Za-z0-9_]. Also isLetter only returns letters and not numbers and underscore...so that does not work for "word characters" under regular expression...Maybe Java has changed since?